# How to perform JSON deserialization for specific string?

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I want to serialize a model in a string like below :-

```
"{"name":"firstName","value":"john"}",
```

And after that i want to deserialize that string.And it should be accessible like this :

```
returnString[0]["name"]  //here name is the name of the property and returnString is the serialized string.
returnString[0]["value"] //here value is the value of the field
```

FYI,we can get above JSON string if we do something like this with javascript:-

```
JSON.stringify(form.serializeArray())
```

But my need is to generate it server side.Can any one suggest me the best way for it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can serialize objects using

```
 Model = {name:'firstname',vlaue:'john'}
JSON.stringify(Model)
```

then when you have a serialized string variable  like this

```
SerializedString='[{"name":"firstName","value":"john"},"name":"LastName","value":"Alexander"}]
'
```

You can get the values  with :

```
ObjectsList =JSON.parse(SerializedString)
```

and then use it like this

```
ObjectsList[0]["name"] 
ObjectsList[0]["value"]
```

I hope it would help

Comment: ,i don't have the serialize string like above.What i want is,i have a model class and i want to serialize that class into above string format.And after that want to get the deserialize objects like you mentioned.

Comment: @Pawan I just Update my answer

Comment: @Pawan Don't forget to "accept" the correct answer, if it solved your problem

Answer (score -1):

Try using Json.Net on the server side to serialize the objects for you.